# I need to send a json obj from Vue(SPA) to node(server)

Tags: json, node.js, http, vue.js

I'm trying to send a form from vue app to a node server with Axion.
but I couldn't get anything in the request on the server side.
I have username and password in vue but I can't send it to the server to process it, plus I could get a response with Postman in x-www-form-urlencoded type and see server works properly.
I try to change type of 'Content-Type' but still didn't get anything on the

---

server side.

Server:

```
    router.options('/login',function(request, response, next) {
console.log(request.body);
    var login = methods.login(request.body.nationalID, request.body.password)
        .then((result) => {
            response.status(200).send({
                success: true,
                roles:   result.roles,
                token:   result.token
            })
        }).catch((err) => {
            response.status(err.code).send({
                success: false,
                message: err.message
            })
        })
});

router.post('/login',function(request, response, next) {

    console.log(request.body);
    var login = methods.login(request.body.nationalID, request.body.password)
        .then((result) => {
            response.status(200).send({
                success: true,
                roles:   result.roles,
                token:   result.token
            })
        }).catch((err) => {
            response.status(err.code).send({
                success: false,
                message: err.message
            })
        })
});
```

and server config:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // <--- Here
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

client side:

```
const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({nationalID:username, password:password})
    };

    return axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/user/login', requestOptions)
        .then(handleResponse)
        .then(user => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            if (user.token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
            }

            return user;
        });
```

Comment: BTW, your server-side `options` code section shouldn't be the same as the `post` code section. When the client sends an `OPTIONS` request, the server is *not* supposed to do any actual work, but to reply with allowed ways to interact with a given URL. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS. Often this is used to support CORS preflight requests. In any case, it should not actually log in the user.

Comment: Another point, instead of local storage, consider using a cookie to store the login token. Set the `secure` and `httpOnly` flags on the cookie to make sure the client A) requires HTTPS connections and B) prevents any Javascript from reading the cookie. This keeps the login cookie safe from theft and the client will automatically use it with every request. Nice longer explanation here: http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/09/04/simple-steps-to-secure-your-express-node-application/

Comment: Of course `secure` only works when you have HTTPS, but you get the point. Sensitive data stored in local storage can be stolen or manipulated, for example by a malicious browser extension. Plus, the client-side application code does not really need to know the actual contents of the logon token in order to function. It's a good strategy to separate the code and the token as strictly as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overdoing the request options.

The `x-www-form-urlencoded` content type is the default for `axios.post()` (and virtually every other HTTP library in existence), and there is no need to `JSON.stringify()` anything. You don't want to send JSON to the server, after all, but form-encoded data.

Just post an object directly:

```
return axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/user/login', {
    nationalID: username,
    password: password
})
    .then( ... )
```